# 404 with Wordpress and GitHub Pages

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have wordpress on the Github pages, what I like to do is to set custom 404 error page created with Wordpress.
But every plugin doesnt work for me. I can use any plugin to set custom 404 page, but it will open the default github pages 404 page.

Also I want to create Redirections with Redirection plugin, but it also doesnt work for me it wont open the url I have set, it will open default 404 github page.

I'm using Wordpress 5.6.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect your Error 404 page, then make a file called "404.html". And paste the code:
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://new-page-url.com"/>`
**EDIT**:

- If you want to redirect your Error 404 page to your home page, then paste this code:
  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/">`

   **Advantages**:
  i. One line code.
  ii. You can delay the timing of redirection according to your need by replacing the `0` from the code.
- And the second one to redirect (used by you,I have excluded the above code) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "https://zigecek.github.io/error"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow <a href='https://zigecek.github.io/'>this</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

**Advantages**: I do not know.
**Disadvantages**:
i. The page will not be redirected if javascript is disabled in the users device, and the other content will be visible.
**At last, I would like to recommend you that do not make a redirection 'Error 404' page, instead you can make a responsive Error 404 page using [Codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=error+404) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+error+404)**

Comment: Did that help or you want something else?

Comment: Nice, but. It is still refreshing angain and again.

Comment: Which page do you exactly want to redirect? I thought you were trying your Github 404 error page to be redirected to Wordpress(.com) 404 error page.

Comment: I have my website https://zigecek.github.io/ and I want if someone opens https://zigecek.github.io/ababababa to redirect to 404 page on https://zigecek.github.io/error. How I said it works good but it is still refreshing. You can try by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I saw it there was a error, because you have redirected to a page which does not exist,i.e., [zigecek.github.io/not-found](https://zigecek.github.io/not-found) ,which gives you again a Error 404 and you are redirected again to the same page. And it created a recursion. Which page do you want to be redirected? The home page or some other page? Give the page url.

Comment: I have edited the answer, have a look at it.

Comment: You have not changed the 'Error 404' page.